# Connect to server from Os X

Tags: macos, localhost, osx-elcapitan

We had in local server web program. When we want to open it from Windows OS we typing simple "server/b2b" to web browser, its opening.
But from macbook (OS X El Captain) its not open when we type "server/b2b"

what should we type to browser from OS X to open local web program?

Comment: localhost:(port number)/b2b

Comment: how can I learn port number?

Comment: Need more info. What web server are you using?